# Postgreslq service active but stopped

Tags: postgresql

On Ubuntu 20.04 I have a Postgresql service active but not running

```
~$ sudo systemctl status postgresql
[sudo] password di ______: 
● postgresql.service - PostgreSQL RDBMS
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (exited) since Tue 2020-12-01 08:18:18 CET; 4h 9min ago
    Process: 1318 ExecStart=/bin/true (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 1318 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

dic 01 08:18:18 ThinkPad-T440 systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL RDBMS...
dic 01 08:18:18 ThinkPad-T440 systemd[1]: Finished PostgreSQL RDBMS.
```

Why does it stop?

How do I troubleshoot this?

Thanks

Comment: /var/log/postgresql would have logs. It would be good if you share them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works as expected. `postgresql` is a service that is meant to start the different PostgreSQL instances, each of these being a distinct service.

Use `sudo systemctl status 'postgresql*'` to see the status of all PostgreSQL services.

Example:

```
$ sudo systemctl status 'postgresql*'
* postgresql.service - PostgreSQL RDBMS
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; enabled; vendor prese
   Active: active (exited) since Wed 2020-12-02 15:42:08 CET; 9h ago
 Main PID: 1880 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Tasks: 0 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/postgresql.service

Dec 02 15:42:08 cyan systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL RDBMS...
Dec 02 15:42:08 cyan systemd[1]: Started PostgreSQL RDBMS.

* postgresql@11-main.service - PostgreSQL Cluster 11-main
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql@.service; indirect; vendor pre
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2020-12-02 15:42:08 CET; 9h ago
 Main PID: 1166 (postgres)
    Tasks: 7 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/system-postgresql.slice/postgresql@11-main.service
           |-1166 /usr/lib/postgresql/11/bin/postgres -D /var/lib/postgresql/11/
           |-1337 postgres: 11/main: checkpointer   
           |-1338 postgres: 11/main: background writer   
           |-1339 postgres: 11/main: walwriter   
           |-1340 postgres: 11/main: autovacuum launcher   
           |-1341 postgres: 11/main: stats collector   
           `-1342 postgres: 11/main: logical replication launcher   

Dec 02 15:42:05 cyan systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL Cluster 11-main...
Dec 02 15:42:08 cyan systemd[1]: Started PostgreSQL Cluster 11-main.
```